# gcc compilation leaves numerous temp files

Tags: gcc, oracle10g, precompiler

I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.4 (it's the latest version) and using gcc 4.1.2 to compile my C project. I've noticed that after the compilation, I get numerous tp* files with 0 bytes each inside the sources folder. I'm using the following options in gcc:

```
gcc -c -ggdb -D__linux -D__ORACLE__ -Wall -I/home/ (more -I here) -o file1.o file1.c
```

This works fine with no erros nor warnings and inside the sources folder I get the final .o files, the source files .c and also numerous files named tp* (for instance tp2YaayN, tp3sYGrz, etc.) and these tp files all have 0 bytes.

I'm also using Oracle's 10g Pro*C/C++ precompiler in some files to embed SQL statements in .pc files and to create .c files which are then compiled by gcc (see [What is an Oracle precompiler?](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a97269/pc_01int.htm#4197)).

So, is there a way of not having these tp files created? I'm not sure these files are created by Oracle's Pro*C/C++ precompiler or by gcc, has anyone had this problem before or knows how to solve it?

Best regards,

Miguel Rentes

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using -pipe so gcc communicates via pipes rather than temp files?

Comment: Hi Rob,

With -pipe it's exactly the same behaviour. I'm starting to suspect this is because of Pro*C/C++ precompiler and not gcc's fault. I'm going to read Pro*C documentation and ask Oracle if this has anything to do with its precompiler. Anyway, thanks for your tip.

Answer (score 0):

gcc does not leave any temporary files after compilation.
they are generated from makefile or the oracle precompiler